# Kaggle - Kernel dies continuously

Tags: machine-learning-model, kaggle

I keep receiving the error message "The kernel appears to have died" when running a simple command such as pd.read_csv(.......) on my Kaggle kernel.
I am not quite sure what the issue. 
Any thoughts of what can i do now to fix that?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the size of your input CSV? 
Kaggle kernel generally dies when the RAM or other resources run out.

Comment: My input file size exceeds 4 Gb and the RAM is 8 Gb.